# How do I force MPlayer to leave cruft behind in the framebuffer?

Tags: arch-linux, mplayer, framebuffer

I use Arch Linux, and so far have successfully used mplayer to play video using fbdev2 output.
However, mplayer sometimes leaves cruft behind in the framebuffer (by cruft, I mean the last rendered video frame, before mplayer exits, is left visible on the screen afterwards), and other times leaves the framebuffer "clean" (I mean, what was behind the video output in the framebuffer gets reinserted when mplayer exits, so no visible evidence, other than the command line, is left of the video).
If possible, I ask for a method of consistently making mplayer leave cruft behind (unrelated reasons I won't go into).
Possibly noteworthy point: I am not asking for alternatives, neither to mplayer nor to framebuffer output. I ask for the above stated.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Turns out the cruft being left behind was caused by leaving another mplayer process running. As long as at least one mplayer process, that writes to the framebuffer, is running, cruft will remain on the framebuffer after other mplayer processes. So far I haven't found other methods of performing this reliably.